# Correct way to resolve a circular reference in make/C code?

Tags: c, makefile

I have two C modules that each use some functionality of the other. In my makefile I have expressed this thus:

```
moduleA.h: common.h moduleB.h
moduleB.h: common.h moduleA.h
```

For obvious reasons this generates a circular reference warning though it goes on to compile fine. What is the correct way of resolving this? Should I refactor the modules to create a third - moduleC - that ties the two together?

Module A is a logging module and module B is a cronjob implementation. Logging uses cronjob to schedule log rotates and cronjob uses logging to tell everyone what it's up to.

Module C would be rather small; simply create a cronjob to call a logging rotate function but logging would then not need to know about cronjob. Cronjob would still depend on logging of course.

Or should I just ignore the warning?

Comment: include guards: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: I always create a new header file when there are two header files that share stuff (struct declarations, for instance) so your proposal of creating **moduleC.h** is fine.

Comment: Suppose `moduleA.h` has changed. How should Make rebuild `moduleB.h`?

Comment: *Something's wrong with your design.* Does one module `include` the other? Do they `include` each other?

Answer (score 0):

You can use soothing like this :

```
￼#ifndef MY_HEADER_FILE_H
#define MY_HEADER_FILE_H

/* Prototypes and others consts and .... */

#endif
```

Hope this help.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you (and tbert too) but my problem is in the makefile only. I always use guards in the include file itself as per your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a version of the logging module `moduleA` that only logs without worrying about `cron` jobs. And then create a new module (perhaps `moduleC`) which is only involved in using `cron` jobs to rotate the logs. Then your dependencies are non-circular:

```
moduleC -> moduleB -> moduleA
```

Comment: Thank you; I thought this would probably be the majority opinion but wanted to throw it out there

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong to state a header file being a prerequisite of a target header file, unless the target is to be **remade** depending on the prerequisite. Normally, an object file target depends on header files, e. g.

```
moduleA.o moduleB.o: common.h moduleA.h moduleB.h
```

Comment: I'm sure that's true. I was intending something like "if a depends on b and b depends on c, d, e and f then changing f should rebuild a"  _even_ _if_ there's nothing as such to be done to rebuild b.

Comment: In that case, I'd just use a rule `b: c d e f; touch b`.